# Nested CupertinoButtons: unnecessary highlighting of the parent button

Tags: flutter

Consider the following code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('My app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: CupertinoButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Container(
              height: 300,
              width: 300,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Center(
                child: CupertinoButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    debugPrint(
                        'Pressing this button shouldnt highlight the parent button');
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: Clicking the child button also highlights the parent button]

Essentially, tapping the child button (green) also highlights the parent button (red).

How to prevent the parent button highlighting when pressing the child button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use Stack to workaround this:

```dart
Stack(
  children: [
    Center(
      child: CupertinoButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: Container(
          height: 300,
          width: 300,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Center(
      child: CupertinoButton(
        onPressed: () {
          debugPrint(
              'Pressing this button shouldnt highlight the parent button');
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haver to remove parent Cupertino button

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('My app'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Center(
              child: CupertinoButton(
                
                onPressed: () {
                  debugPrint(
                      'Pressing this button shouldnt highlight the parent button');
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can warp your parant  cupertino button into themedata then you have to give parameter  called ```splashcolor : Colors.transparent```  of ThemeData Widget.                like this ```Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
    splashColor: Colors.transparent,
    highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
    hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
  )
  child: child,
)```

Comment: I actually need the parent button. I can't remove it. It does its job.